# Can data be loaded from MongoDB to auto generate webpages with EJS?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, ejs, auto-generate

I am a student working on making an app using MongoDB, Node, EJS, etc. Learning about EJS and partials brought a question to mind. Is is possible to simply create an EJS template for a page, and ultimately have a full stack app scan a MongoDB database for entries, and then dynamically have a webpage generated for each entry in the DB?

This way you could presumably have a database wherein if you add an entry to it, a webpage is auto generated for the data field you added to it.

I am sorry if this is a vague question or doesn't make much sense, but it's something I thought of and was curious about.

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two answers: one is "yes, easily" and the other is "yes, but it'll be harder", and it depends on what exactly you mean.

If you just mean that for each Mongo record, you can go to a page like `/puppies/[mongo-id]`, yes, that is totally possible. Here's how you do it, with an example "puppies" app:

- Set up a route for the end point `/puppies/:id`. The `/:id` is a route param that will catch things like `/puppies/1`, `/puppies/2`, etc. and attach them to the request object on `req.params`.
- In that route, use `req.params.id` to search Mongo for that particular puppies record. `Puppy.findById(req.params.id)` or similar (it has been a hot second since I used mongo & mongoose but it'll be something like that)
- Make an EJS template for a puppy page that you can plug information into. I assume you have seen already a syntax similar to this: `res.render('path/to/template', { name: 'Spot', breed: 'Border Collie', goodness: 'extreme' })` -- passing data into a template. You can make the template so that the information that you have about each puppy is the same, and thus no matter what puppy you put into the page, it will look the same and be valid HTML.
- Pass the information that you got from requesting the puppy with ID of `req.params.id` into the template.

Voila! Now, when you create a puppy, you can immediately go to `puppies/my-new-puppys-id` and see your puppy there.

Second answer! If you mean that you'd like to create an HTML page for each individual puppy -- I think personally that this is overkill when you can just do it with templates as described above? But yes, you can.

The EJS view engine takes in a template and some values, and spits out a string. When we use `res.render`, right, we're taking that string and sending it to the browser. However, you can also use `ejs.render` (see the [EJS docs](https://ejs.co/) -- it works the same pretty much as `res.render` with the template path and the data object, just without sending the response.) to get the string without sending it as the response. Then you can take that string and create a new `html` file with it, using the `fs` (file system) module.

So:

- POST request to `/puppies`
- Route handler creates the new puppy in the mongo database
- With the new puppy, use `ejs.render` to generate an HTML string
- Use the `fs` module to create a new puppy HTML file.

However, like I said, I think this second way is super pointless since it is pretty much exactly the same thing as templating, just with way more steps.

Hope this helps! Good luck with your course!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It really helped deepen my knowledge of this topic, and inspired several google searches that helped me figure out exactly how to implement what I'm doing. I really appreciate your time.